# dictate order of dynamically rendered table React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, amazon-dynamodb

I am dynamically rendering a table from an aws dynamo database. I want to have the newest posts rendered first. I am using the createdAt variable as the key but the table still renders randomly. I'm having trouble figuring out whats wrong and would appreciate the help. Code:

```
 export default class Home extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
   isLoading: true,
   sort: {
    column: null,
    direction: 'desc',
   }
  };

  this.onSort = this.onSort.bind(this);

 }

 async componentDidMount() {
  if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
   return;
 }

 try {
  const results = await this.notes();
  this.setState({ notes: results });
 } catch (e) {
   alert(e);
 }

  this.setState({ isLoading: false });
 }

 notes() {
  return invokeApig({ path: "/notez" });
 }

 handleNoteClick = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.props.history.push(event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href"));
 }

 onSort(column) {
   return(function(e) {
     let direction = this.state.sort.direction;

     if (this.state.sort.column === column){

      direction = this.state.sort.direction === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
     }

     const sortedData = this.state.notes.sort((a, b) => {
      if(column === 'date') {

       return a.createdAt - b.createdAt;
      } 
     });

     if(direction === 'desc'){
      sortedData.reverse();
     }

     this.setState({
      notes: sortedData,
      sort: {
        column,
        direction,
      }
     });
  }).bind(this); 
 }

 renderNotesList(notes) {

  var styles = { 
   progress: {
     backgroundColor: "#ffff00",
     color: '#000000'
   },
   completed: {
     backgroundColor: "#66CD00",
     color: '#000000'
   }
  }

  return (
   <div>
    <Table responsive hover>
      <thead>
        <tr>        
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Employee</th>
          <th className="sortable" onClick={this.onSort('date')}>
            Created 
          </th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {this.state.notes.map((note) => 
          <tr 
            key={note.createdAt}
            href={`/notes/${note.noteId}`}
            onClick={this.handleNoteClick}
            className="workOrders"
          >             
            <td>{note.title}</td>
            <td>{note.employee}</td>
            <td>{new Date(note.createdAt).toLocaleString()}</td>
            {note.jobStatus === 'In Progress' || note.jobStatus !== 'Completed' ? <td style={styles.progress}>{note.jobStatus}</td> : <td style={styles.completed}>{note.jobStatus}</td>}          
          </tr>
        )}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  </div>
 );
}
```

The createdAt is stored as integer value in the database:

[image: createdAt List]

I thought I'd be able to render the list from newest to oldest since the createdAt date that is most recent is higher in value. Is this possible?

Comment: Looks like you have the right idea with using `sort` on `this.state.notes`. Can you show us what `this.states.notes` looks like?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are doing a default sort for the initial render. `onSort` looks like it sorts them, but it's not being called until you click on the table header. You need to sort them by createdAt by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sorting the data on initial render. You only sort them after table header column "Created" is clicked. You can try adding `this.onSort('date')` after the `this.setState({ notes: results });` in your `componentDidMount` function or better yet, just sort the `results` before passing it to the state:

```
const results = await this.notes();
const notes = results.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.createdAt - b.createdAt;
});
this.setState({ notes });
```

Then of course you don't want to forget to change your default sort column in constructor from `null` to `'date'`.